# Curve fitting, but I want to guarantee only one inflection point

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I often find myself fitting a scatter plot, and knowing that the 'true fit' should have only one inflection point.  Any ideas for forcing a fit that will obey this?
I am using Matlab and Microsoft Excel
Many thanks

Comment: Limit the fit to a quadtratic curve

Comment: I guess this should be cubic. Quadratic curves do not reveal inflection points. However I would suggest to use a constrained minimizer such as COBYLA which allows for putting constraints on the derivatives (if known). For your problem you should constrain the 3thd derivative to be either positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

I like to use spline smoothing with Akaike information criteria, and while it is a hyper-parametric fit and has a large number of analytic candidate inflection points, the smoothed data at the sample points tends to reveal only what is within the data.

If your data doesn't actually have an inflection point, this is indicated.  If it does, it is also usually captured.  Statistical jargon for an important cousin to this is called a "[non-informative prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior)".

Try slides 30-31 here: [link](http://hdl.handle.net/2286/f2vkvseenfr).

**Option 2:**

If you have an older version of MatLab then you can specify the exact model easily in the "cftool" (not the same as sftool) then get m-file that gives how you put it into your own script.  Pick a model appropriate to your data.